# How do I convert current python program to multi prosessing/multi threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Sorry to ask this question as a new python starter, I have a working python program to be converted into multiprocessing or multithreading, here is the working py's structure:

```
class XMLToJson():
    def __init__(self, region=None, flow=None, path=None, output=None):

        def run(self):

def run_from_cmd():
    XMLToJson().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    XMLToJson().run()
```

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can tell me how to do the conversion.

Thank you very much.

P.S.

The following is the framework I am thinking how to fit into it:

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread, Lock
import time


def worker(l):
    while True:
        l.acquire()
        print ('in worker:' + str(current_thread()))
        l.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = Lock()
    print ('in main: ' + str(current_thread()))
    threads = [Thread(target=worker, args=[l]) for i in range(5)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I modified the original working program from run() to main_process(), and set the target from worker to main_process,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = Lock()
    print ('in main: ' + str(current_thread()))
    threads = [Thread(target=main_process, args=[l]) for i in range(5)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

but the program doesn't even pass the compile, error out in target=main_process.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You should look into `Threading` and `multiprocessing` modules

Comment: yes I did, I am to update in the OP now.

Comment: have a look here https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html, threading is one process multiple threads, multiprocessing is multiple processes, cause of python GIL, multiprocessing is better use of the cpu cores but sometimes overkill, what is your use case exactly?

Comment: Can you share the error message you get?

Comment: this is the error: [link]https://snag.gy/SxOY7A.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks quite a bit of specifics. What is your program doing? Why do you want to multiprocess/thread? What is your input/output? What is there to multiprocess/multithread?

If what you have is a script that does `input => transform => output` and terminates, multiprocessing/threading would be just a way to process several sets of input at the same time to gain time. In that case you could either call your script several times with each set of inputs, or pass the multi-inputs to a single instance of your multi-threaded script where you use e.g. `binge` library (`pip install binge`) to deal with multiprocessing:

```
from binge import B
result = B(worker, n=5)(....)
```

where `worker` is your transform function, n the number of times it should happen, and `....` your inputs to be sent to the 5 parallel worker instances - mind that if you have n=5, then your inputs should be either length 5 (distributed over workers), or 1 (given identically to each worker).

cf: [binge documentation](https://github.com/ceyzeriat/binge/)